# Devise session resetting upon external source POSTing URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionscript-3, flash, authentication, devise

It's an interesting problem, really, for all you Devise masters you there.

We have Devise setup with OmniAuth, but the issue happens regardless if you are logged in via Facebook, or logged in via a normal username.  What happens is we have a Flash game embedded on our website.  When you finish playing the game, the game will submit your score to the Rails backend:

```
request = new URLRequest("http://mydomain.com:2012/games/1/leaderboards/13/submitLeaderboardStatistic");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 

var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
var variables : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.game_value = aScore;
variables.game_id = 1;
variables.unique_identifier = "com.onecoolgameaday.highscores";
variables.time_stamp = new Date();

request.data = variables;  

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_complete);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
loader.load(request);
```

The URL is sent out to our URL.  The Controller (Leaderboards are nested underneath Games) gets the url information in the submitLeaderboardStatistic method.  This method deals with the information.  In this method, I call `current_user` to get the current User, the one who submitted the actual score.  Problem is, current_user returns nil.

Apparently, what is happening, is once the game Launches that URL POST request, devise invalidates the session (or something), so I cannot tell who submitted the score.

Why is the current signed in user being "kicked off" once the Flash Game send the URL?  How do I fix this so I can say "user XXX submitted this score."

Thank you!

Rails: 3.2.2
Ruby: 1.9.2
Devise: 1.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the form you are submitting have a valid CSRF token? I think Devise calls reset_session if the csrf token is invalid or doesn't exist.

Comment: This is actually the cause (I found out a while ago). The POST request did /not/ have a valid CSRF token, so it was resetting the session.  I ended up passing in the CSRF token into the flash application, and it uses it when it sends the request.  This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set full URL address to the "/games/1/leaderboards/13/submitLeaderboardStatistic". Probably reason is cross-domail-policy, which should be received from the server, when you using POST method to the different domain.

Comment: For security reasons, I didn't post the fully URL on Stack Overflow (for the reason you say).  The URL is of the form "http://mydomain.com:2012/games/1/leaderboards/13/submitLeaderboardStatistic".  I've updated the OP to reflect this.  Thanks for posting!